# SQL Select by DayOfWeek As Column Header

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am writing a SQL Report, that reports on targets by Day Of Week, so for example I will need to achieve the output in a similar format as:  TargetName, Target%, Mon, Tue, Weds, Thurs etc, each day of the week will show how many times this target was hit for that day.

I have no problems writing the SQL to join the relevant tables for each target name. My question is how do I include the additional headers and display the relevant data by header in the above format?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: What means "Target%"?

Comment: This could be 75, 80 etc. This will vary each time.

Comment: What dbms are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? This makes a difference as date functions differ.

Comment: So Target% is a column of that table? Or a percentage we must calculate? If the latter, according to what formula?

Comment: Ignore Target, it was just added to explain the example.  I will calculate this.  The question is mainly around the headers and getting the data into the column below for that day of the week, cheers

Comment: Also, there could be about 15 different TargetNames, so if there is anything faster to write than a case statement that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server use **DatePart** with **weekday** to know what weekday the date represents. Then sum for the according day with a case construct.

```
select 
  targetname, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 2 then hits end) as monday, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 3 then hits end) as tuesday, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 4 then hits end) as wednesday, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 5 then hits end) as thursday, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 6 then hits end) as friday, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 7 then hits end) as saturday, 
  sum(case when datepart(weekday,logdate) = 1 then hits end) as sunday
from targets
group by targetname
order by targetname;
```

DatePart with weekday depends on the setting of `DATEFIRST`. Above statement assumes that first day is set to Sunday.

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL Server not MYSQL

Comment: Also, there could be about 15 different TargetNames, so if there is anything faster to write than a case statement that would be great.

Comment: Oops, yes, Google misled me. In SQL-Server you can use DatePart with weekday: `DATEPART ( weekday, logdate )`. Unfortunately this relies on the setting of DATEFIRST. If you know your Setting, and it's guaranteed to stay thus, use it. Otherwise one must use tricks, e.g. find the time span from a known date to calculate the weekday. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: A CASE Statement should be *very* fast. No reads, neither logically nor even physically, simply some evaluation. You won't get this any faster.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried out what you sent and the format seems to be fine, and changed this to datepart, however how do I calculate all 15 targets for that one day of the week?

Comment: Well, you group by target, so if you have 15 different targets, you get 15 result records, each showing the hits per day for that target. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Lets say the Target table has a TargetID and there is another table named TargetName. For every Target I would need to Join to the TargetName table to find the total targets for Monday for Say the targetName of MobileCallsOut? SO the Columns on the left of the table could have 15 target names. How do I find out the total for that Target on Monday, thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: So there is a target name 'MobileCallsOut' and there are many (sub) targets leading to this target name? And you want to count per targetname: `COUNT(DISTINCT targetid)`? Is this what you are looking for?